# API Fetch failed with No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I've been running out of my mind trying to deal with this problem.

I'm running React.js on my local machine under http://localhost:3000 and i'm trying to use the fetch method to load some data from `http://api.population.io:80/1.0/countries`

According to the API owner "The standard response format is JSON (application/json) with CORS for cross-domain requests."

I've tried various combinations of headers and what i have right now is this setup:

```
fetch("http://api.population.io:80/1.0/countries",{
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: new Headers({
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
    })
})
```

According to Chrome, the following headers are being sent through the request:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-headers,access-control-allow-origin,content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/reports
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
```

But of course, the server returns a 403 status code with the following message:

> Failed to load http://api.population.io/1.0/countries: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403. If an opaque response
>   serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the
>   resource with CORS disabled.

I know about the chrome plugin which allows me to work around this issue but this is not ideal and i'm afraid i don't know what to do, i've been trying to fix this my whole day and i finally gave up at 4am after trying almost everything i could find.

If there's someone smart enough to enlighten me, i'd definitely appreciate it and i'm even willing to ship to you a bunch of beers just to help me sort this out.

Comment: I think the problem is on server-side, you should add `cors` on server.

Comment: It seems the problem, at least in my case, was the actual fetch method. By using axios, the request completes just fine and returns what I need without cors.

Comment: @Adiran, try to add `'Accept': 'application/json',` to `headers`

Answer (score 1):

CORS headers are something that need to be properly set in the response from the server. You cannot make CORS work by supplying more headers in the request. It's not uncommon for responses to omit CORS headers in the case of a non-successful response (as is the case for you - you are getting a 403 response).

So, you need to figure out why the response was not successful, and why it does not include the CORS headers. Either way, you cannot send more CORS headers in the request to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that fetch is failing on the standard OPTIONS request done on CORS mode.  You can confirm by accessing the link http://api.population.io/1.0/countries on your browser and press the button OPTIONS, the response you get is the same response fetch is getting when accessing on CORS mode.

You should fix this on server.

**Edit**: Furthermore, the problem seems to be that domain api.population.io is redirecting to CloudFront and as the message says, the CDN only supports cachable requests. Seems to be the consequence of an architectural decision of bypassing a Django REST API through CloudFront that is a CDN Service.

If the request is made without CORS and its previous OPTIONS request , it works.